# Does the substitution $u = \dfrac{y}{x}$ still be applicable for homogenous functions of degree $k$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that I have the differential equation: 
 $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y) $$
According to the book, if $f(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $0$ ($f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = f(x,y)$) then we can use the substitution $u = \dfrac{y}{x}$ to make the differential equation separable.

**My question is**: does this substitution still be applicable if $f(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ ($f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda^kf(x,y)$) ?

Comment: Why don't you try with an explicit example?

Comment: @Siminore: it works but I am asking if there is a theorem or something like that

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation

Comment: @Siminore: I know but nothing helpfull there

Comment: @Siminore : trying an example is a proof?!

Comment: Sooner or later you will have to work on your problems. For the time being, you hope to find a solution without any effort.

Comment: What is the relationship with the question? Anyway, you need to know if a technique works for a more general kind of equations. Did you try? Does it work? If not, why?

Comment: @ I try to prove for the general case but I think it does not work Anyway, can I post my answer?

Comment: @Siminore: Please check my answer, does it really answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $u = \dfrac{y}{x}$does not work always for homogeneous functions of degree $k \neq 0$

$f(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ means that:
$$f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda^k f(x,y) $$
So, $f(x,y) = \dfrac{f(\lambda x, \lambda y)}{\lambda^k}$
, Now put $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{x}$, we get: $f(x,y) = x^kf\left(1, \dfrac{y}{x} \right) $
which means (for $k\neq 0$) that $f(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $u$ so this substitution does not make sense.

The goal clearly of the substitution $y = ux$ is to make $f(x,y)$ a function of one variable $u$ which is the case only if $k=0$.

$$ $$